# How to solve 404 error for php app on vercel?

Tags: php, github, deployment, http-status-code-404, vercel

I deployed my project to vercel without any database set up and I have a 404 error.

Heres the github repo to the project im working on: https://github.com/DinoBarton/RankHali2.0

also soz if this is a silly question, im new to all of this!

I thought vercel had a problem finding the page to open so I renamed one of the files index.php but I still have the 404 error

Comment: You can manually add `vercel.json` in the root and add `routes` in this file.

Comment: Thanks @Asif I will give it a go and will let you know.